# Splitting a merged column by space with some empty values of dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract tables from some pdfs files where some columns are extracted like the below one where ideally, A,B,C are three different column.

```
merged_col = 'A B C'
df[merged_col]  
                 'A B C'
                 '1 2 3'
                 '6 3 5'
                   '4 6'
                 '3 5 3'
```

I did :

```
s = merged_col.split(' ')[0]
t = merged_col.split(' ')[1]
u = merged_col.split(' ')[2]
df[s],df[t],df[u] = df[merged_col].str.rsplit(n=2, expand=True)
```

Which is working fine apart from the cases where a field is empty like the 3rd row. It's giving me this:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
6,3,5
4,6
3,5,3
```

What I am expecting (missing values to be handled correctly):

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
6,3,5
  4,6
3,5,3
```

Comment: What are you asking for? To fill the missing data, skip those entries etc.

Comment: I have updated the question now. I want the missing values to be captured correctly

Comment: If you're coming from a string, there's no way for the code to know if the '4 6' row is missing the first or last value unless you get another space in there on either side?

Comment: As JMC says, Unfortunately if the line with the missing value is formatted exactly as   '4 6' then it would be read as A:4, B:6. It might be more beneficial to clean the data ingest so there are clear delimiters and missing values where expected

Comment: If you've not used [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#table-extraction-methods) it's worth trying out. I've had better results with its table extraction functions. The settings are all configurable which may help you get an actual empty "cell" instead of a truncated string (assuming it doesn't work using the default settings.)